# Compiler error after adding a new Configuration in project

Tags: ios, xcode

I encountered an issue after setting up a new value for Configuration when building (after reading the following post: [Different App Icons for your iOS Beta, Dev, and Release builds](http://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-beta-dev-and-release-builds/)). The error message is as follows:

> ld: file not found:
> /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeAppName-.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SomeAppName.app/SomeAppName
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

I'm not sure how to fix it, checked and double checked with the article and I did follow everything as explained.

Edit: The error appears to be from the Tests target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29887473/2124535

> I solved it in Xcode 6 very easy like this:
>
> 1. Select your project in the project navigator.
> 2. Select the YourProjectTests under targets
> 3. Under General tab change the Host Application from the drop down
> 4. Build and run.
>
> This problem happened to me because I renamed my project and the tests could't find it anymore. - Yowza7

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Tests target did not help for me.

I posted a solution that did work here: [Created new XCode Configuration and Scheme - linker is suddenly failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626055/created-new-xcode-configuration-and-scheme-linker-is-suddenly-failing/40661027#40661027)

It basically involves telling Xcode to look for the libraries created using the Release configuration.