# cordova - Xcode got error command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Got error "Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code"

```
 Ionic:

    ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

       Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4

       @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3

       @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3

       @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3

       @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

    Cordova:

       cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2

       Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5

       Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3,

    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 5 other plugins)

    System:

       Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 

       ios-deploy        : 1.9.2

       ios-sim           : 5.0.8

       NodeJS            : v10.15.3 

       npm               : 6.4.1

       OS                : macOS Mojave

       Xcode             : Xcode 10.3
```

The project just created and only add plugin cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.

I add iOS platform then run the project and get error "Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code"

In Xcode already add libraries:

- cordova.framework
- webkit.framework
- storeKit.framework
- CoreLocation.framework

I think I already try this. Click the Target project >> at general >> change name in host application. It happened because i change the project's name but it still using the previous name, but I cannot find the host application. Then, I change the project name using the previous name which state in error then remove platform iOS >> add iOS >> run but still got the same error.

[ld: file not found: linker command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665196/ld-file-not-found-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)
https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker/issues/236

How can I fix this?

Here is the screenshot.

[image: error]

Comment: can you share the exact screenshot may be I can help?

Comment: Looks like your *Framework Search Paths*, or similar, are messed-up.  It's looking for the Cordova framework within the built app bundle, which doesn't seem right.